# Add tag to a nickname

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The thing i am trying to do is add a tag before the nickname with a command in which i specify the member and the tag. For example,  will change to [tag] . Also, i am not sure why the before & after do not work in this case. I have done it before but not in a command. Below is the current code i have.

```py
    @command(name="settag", brief="Set Tag to Member")
    async def set_tag(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, tag):
        newtag = [ + tag + ] + before.nick
        await member.edit(nick=newtag)
        await ctx.send(f"{before.member.display_name}'s nickname changed to {after.member.display_name}")

        await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Mhm not sure why but some of my message got deleted. The example i wanted to show was that the command is supposed to change nickname to [tag] nickname and in the channel to send nickname's nickname changed to [tag] nickname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newtag` it's not a string, and it should be, simply do:

```py
newtag = '[' + tag + ']' + before.nick
# or using f-strings
newtag = f'[{tag}]{before.nick}'
```

Also, `before.nick` it's not working because you didn’t define  `before` you can simply

```py
before_nick = ctx.author.nick 
newtag = '[' + tag + ']' + before_nick
```